# External disk with encrypted Time Machine partition doesn't eject properly

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, encryption, time-machine, disk-utility

I'm not sure when this started, maybe when I setup my Time Machine partition to be encrypted or maybe at a particular OS update, but the **Time Machine drive no longer ejects properly**. I'd love some help on this one!

Here's what happens:

- I have an external drive with two partitions: an encrypted partition for Time Machine, and another AFPS (Encrypted) one called "Extras". The drive plugs directly into my MacBook Pro 2015 15" running macOS 10.14.4
- On a fresh restart with the drive plugged into a USB port, the two partitions appear normally in both Finder and Disk Utility. Time Machine works and everything is good.
- If I eject the drive (either from Finder or Disk Utility), it appears to eject normally (disappearing from Finder, greying out in Disk Utility) until I actually pull the USB cable out of the MacBook. Instead of the greyed-out drive disappearing altogether from Disk Utility, nothing changes.
- If I plug the drive back in, then the Extras drive appears again in Finder but Time Machine does not. In Disk Utility, it looks a little weird (see below): a second drive appears with the same name (but nothing under it), and the Extras drive appears under the initial drive.

After plugging hard drive back in:

[image]

I've tried various combinations of `unmount`/`unmountDisk`/`eject` with the `diskutil` command, and once in a while a command sequence does work… but it's never repeatable. Now I just have to restart the computer whenever I want to access Time Machine again.

Any ideas here? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main reason is that your Time Machine is making a backup at the moment you are trying to eject the drive. That is why you sometimes succeed (TM already finished the job) to unmount it and other times not.

[This](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/time-machine-volume-not-showing-up-after-disk-was-not-ejected-properly.2027500/) link may also help you. It describes the solution of a similar problem.

Before you try anything from below, I **highly recommend** you to check your Time Machine and make sure that it is not trying to make a backup while you are trying to unmount the drive.

The solution from link:

> The way to diagnose if your issue is the same - go to System Information       utility, and see if your drive is showing up under USB section. Mine was    there, so it was clear that it's not the issue with the drive itself.
>
> The thing is - when it is trying to get mounted, OSX is launching a process "fsck_hfs". It's the same process that appears when you're performing "first aid" on the disk, so the OSX is trying to check the disk before mounting it.
>
> What I did - I force quit this process in Activity Monitor utility, then the disk appeared in Disk Utility, and I was able to perform First Aid on it manually.
>
> After that Time Machine was refusing to use the disk and complained it was "read only", so I had to turn Time machine off, unmount the disk, restart, mount the disk and enable Time Machine again.

Comment: Please include the solution from the link into your answer. As it is, this is basically a link-only answer.